# Windows 7 can't see HDD

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, linux-mint

I use a dual-boot between Windows 7 and Linux Mint.

When I start my computer and choose Windows 7, it does not detect the additional disk data.  However, if I start the PC with Linux Mint, and then restart PC and run Windows 7, then the additional disk is visible.

Disk Management:

[image: Disk Management Screenshot]

What can I do?

Comment: Is the data disk formatted with a file system Windows is compatible with?

Comment: Partitioning : Master Boot Record

Comment: I formatted disk in Linux ... Master Boot Record / Partition type : HPFS/NTFS . This means that I need format the drive in Windows?

Comment: Does Windows Disk management show the drive, and if so, what does it report the file system as?  If it shows it as a valid NTFS partition, did you assign it a drive letter in Windows?

Comment: After running first Linux Mint and than restart to Windows7 Disk Management show drive and letter.     http://i66.tinypic.com/2gu9xr8.png          If I run first Windows than Disk Management don't show drive and letter

Comment: That image is WAY too small to be read, so can you post a hi-res version so we can actually read it? :)

Comment: Oh sorry :-)   http://tinypic.com/r/2ugm0k7/9

Comment: Ok, so out of the partitions in the picture, exactly which one(s) aren't visible in Windows?

Comment: Disk 0 ( Data and Films )

Comment: So let me get this straight, if you just reboot the computer or if you start from a cold boot, it does not react the same?

Comment: Yes. If I start first Linux Mint then restart and start Windows than Disk 0 is visible. If I start first Windows than Disk 0 isn't visible ... I have update : In BIOS under hard Disk Drives : 1st Drive AHCI WD5000AADJ and ( interesting ) 2 nd Drive AHCI      - ( without a label disk )

Comment: Here are pictures of Windows Disk management if I start Windows first : http://tinypic.com/r/dnhcic/9 and after confirmation this : http://tinypic.com/r/28vshap/9

Answer (score 0):

All partitions formatted as NTFS or FAT would be visible inside Windows. Any partitions formatted in ext4 wouldn't show up. In case you have formatted it as NTFS and it is still not showing up, try removing and reassigning the drive letter (using cmd if necessary). Reformat if it still doesn't show up.

Comment: I uninstalled and re-installed cables from  HDD, but nothing happens ... So tomorrow reformat HDD. Thank for help